# Xcode Plugin of Jenkins not working with Xcode9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am using Xcode plugin of Jenkins which is working for Xcode 8.3 but it is not compatible with Xcode 9.0 because of changes in code signing .

I am getting the error as below :

> error: exportArchive: "SwiftDemo.app" requires a provisioning profile.
>        Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""SwiftDemo.app" requires a provisioning profile."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="SwiftDemo.app" requires a
>   provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to
>   the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property
>   list.}
>
> ** EXPORT FAILED **

Answer (score 6):

I was also getting this error. But now solved the issue. I can build successfully in Xcode9.0 and Xcode9.2.

Here are the steps mentioned below to overcome above error.

- Manually generate and export the IPA file with Xcode. This will create a file name ExportOptions.plist in the exported folder.
- Copy that file to workspace root folder.
- In Jenkin General build settings, uncheck “Pack application, build and sign .ipa?”, and check “Generate Archive?”.
- And last, add an Execute shell like this,

  ```
   xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/build/YourProject.xcarchive -exportPath ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/archive -exportOptionsPlist ${WORKSPACE}/ExportOptions.plist
  ```

Answer (score 0):

what works for me:

1. Keychain: Move two signing certificates (iphone dev and iphone distr) from Login to System.
2. make sure that "trust" property set to "system default"

Comment: But How Jenkins will access System Keychain

Comment: Jenkins access to your Keychain through overall password mentioned in http://localhost:8080/configure in 'Xcode Builder' section.<br/><br/>

and configuring section in job: **'Code signing & OS X keychain options'**<br/><br/>

also you can use plugin, which make configuring little bit easy. [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin)<br/><br/>

please see some tutorials here:
[link] (https://medium.com/@cherrmann.com/continuous-integration-and-delivery-for-ios-with-jenkins-and-fastlane-part-1-3b17f1901a73)