# xcode 9 Manual Signing ** EXPORT FAILED **

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcode9, provisioning-profile

I am trying to  Continuous integrate using Jenkins for Ios project. i am using below command to manually specify the code signing identity and provisioning profile.

> /usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace "Project.xcworkspace" -scheme
>   "projectTest" -archivePath build/Project -configuration Release
>   archive CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual
>   PROVISIONING_PROFILE=”CompanyNameQAAdhocDistribution”
>   CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: xxxxxxx xxxx (xxxxxxxxxx)"
>
> ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
>
> For Exporting the IPA I am using below command.
>
> /usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath
>   "build/Project.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/Project.ipa"
>   -exportOptionsPlist "Build/Project.xcarchive/Info.plist"
>
> Error Message:
>
> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""ProjectTest.app"
>   requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications and Apple
>   Pay features." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="ProjectTest.app"
>   requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications and Apple
>   Pay features., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the
>   "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property
>   list.}
>
> ** EXPORT FAILED **

Able to Export from IDE, But unable to do it via from command. Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: Your statement telling (requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications and Apple Pay features) : push notifications and apple pay features are not included in your provisioning profile.

Comment: @shivam it is included working fine from IDE. but unable to do it via command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try specify correct profile in exportOptions.plist example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>xxxxx</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>*com.xxxxxx*</key>
        <string>*profile name*</string>
    </dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And then load it with:
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist "path/to/this.plist" ...

And make sure you use correct one. Its better to use IDs of profiles than names or delete all old profiles from disk.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Used above described pattern. But got the This error.

Comment: Error Domain=IDEProfileQualificationErrorDomain Code=3 "Provisioning profile "companyQAAdhocDistribution" is not an "iOS App Development" profile." UserInfo={IDEProfileQualificationError_Profile=<DTDKProvisioningProfile 0x7fe4ae8beb30: UUID:XXXXXXX-XXXXX, name: companyQAAdhocDistributionQAAdhocDistribution, team: XXXXXX (XXXXX, Inc.), platform: iOS>, NSLocalizedDescription=Provisioning profile "companyQAAdhocDistribution" is not an "iOS App Development" profile.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Comment: change "development" to "ad-hoc" or to method you need. (in the exportOptions.plist file)

Answer (score 1):

In my case...I had the wrong bundle identifier under targetapp.plist --> provisioning profile(i.e targetapp bundle id and provisioning profile bundle id is different). After changing it to the correct one ( targetapp bundle id to provisionig profile) this issue got resolved

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. I am successfully Exported IPA in Xcode 9.0 and 9.2

[Xcode Plugin of Jenkins not working with Xcode9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220844/xcode-plugin-of-jenkins-not-working-with-xcode9-0/49686688#49686688)